# Set Viewstate from a query string

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

If I load this page without a querystring the !IsPostBack sets the viewstate variable correctly and it is available to my button click event. However if I set M to something and try to initiate the button click automatically before the Page_load event is closed, the veiwstate variable is null and throws an error.  Any Ideas how I can work around this? Can I directly pass the Viewstate object to the button1_Click event somehow? Is there an event after page load that I can tap to send my button click if a querystring was present?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["S"]))
        {
            TextBox1.Text = Request.QueryString["S"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["T"]) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["M"]))
            {
                Button1_Click(null, null);
            }

        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["T"]))
        {
            TextBox2.Text = Request.QueryString["T"];
            Button1_Click(null, null);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["M"]))
        {
            ViewState["checkedOEM"] = Request.QueryString["M"];
            Button1_Click(null, null);
        }
        if (ViewState["checkedOEM"] == null)
        {
            CheckBox1.Checked = true;
            checkedOEM = CheckBox1.Text;
            ViewState["checkedOEM"] = checkedOEM;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error, and on what line? Also why are you using ViewState at all here?

Comment: Its a null reference exception in the Button1_Click event on:                         checkedOEM = ViewState["checkedOEM"].ToString();

Comment: As to why I'm using view state, I have several checkboxes that fire events to ensure only one checkbox can be selected. When they fire a postback, I lose which one is set.  It is easier to set the selected one in a variable than to try and figure out which of several is currently set. I also have need of them in other methods as a check to do further processing under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

So I broke up the Page_Load event into the prior and post events to get the behavior I was looking for.

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["M"]))
    {
        ViewState["checkedOEM"] = Request.QueryString["M"];            
    }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //hide all fields untill they need to be shown
    HyperLink2.Visible = false;
    HyperLink3.Visible = false;
    Image1.Visible = false;
    debugLabel.Text = null;
    debugLabel2.Text = null;

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LinkButton1.Visible = false;

        if (ViewState["checkedOEM"] == null)
        {
            CheckBox1.Checked = true;
            checkedOEM = CheckBox1.Text;
            ViewState["checkedOEM"] = checkedOEM;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["M"]))
        {
            CheckBox1.Visible = false;
            CheckBox2.Visible = false;
            CheckBox3.Visible = false;
            CheckBox4.Visible = false;
            Button1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    lblStatus.Text = string.Empty;
}

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["S"]))
    {
        TextBox1.Text = Request.QueryString["S"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["T"]) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["M"]))
        {
            Button1_Click(null, null);
        }

    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["T"]))
    {
        TextBox2.Text = Request.QueryString["T"];
        Button1_Click(null, null);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["M"]))
    {            
        Button1_Click(null, null);
    }
}
```